# Is it possible to "link" two or more folders in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have two PCs with Windows 8.1 in the same LAN.
One of the two PCs has an external USB storage HDD.

I'd like to know if it's possible, and eventually how, to logically link two or more folders that exist in the 2 PCs + ExtHDD so that I can see the content of all of them as a single folder.

Comment: With Windows 7, it would be possible, using the “Library” feature.